# How to get ID3 tag info from Dropbox files?

Tags: php, id3, dropbox-api

Is there an easy and efficient way to gather ID3 tag info from music files in my dropbox folder using the PHP API? I'm able to loop through the files and pull the information using the getFile API method and the id3_get_tag php function but this is very slow as you increase the number of music files.

Is there an efficient way to grab the id3 information from a large directory of music files?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [PHP Reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/) library, which should do what you're after using pure php. If it's faster than id3_get_tag or not, I do now know.